# Visualising numpy arrays in PyCharm

Tags: numpy, pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm for developing and debugging numpy code, and I would like to have a similar tool for inspecting numpy arrays. According to this link https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/scientific_tools.html there is built-in numpy array viewer. However, when stopped in the debugger, all I could see is this:

[image: Debug window]

which is a really low-level representation. Is this really what they mean by the "array viewer" or there is the feature hidden in somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To view a NumPy array, run your project in a debug mode and find the NumPy array in the variables list shown in the PyCharm`s graphical debugger. Right-click it and select “View as Array”.

It should look like this (not the low-level representation you're seeing.):

[image]

Source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/11/third-pycharm-4-eap-numpy-array-viewer-ipython-notebook-improvements-and-more/

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that one out :)

Answer (score 1):

If a numpy array is an image and you want to see its content visually, you can use OpenCV Image Viewer Plugin, which I've just released. It works with any JetBrains IDE, which support Python (directly or via plugin).

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]